# Indefinite article - Is it necessary?

Tags: articles

Which is right: '**There is lack of information**' or '**There is a lack of information**'?

Comment: I searched the [iWeb](https://corpus.byu.edu/iweb/) corpus and found 13k results for `there [be] a|the lack of` and 1k for `there [be] lack of`, where `[be]` denotes all forms of the verb *be* (*is*, *was*, etc.).

Comment: I've never come across **there is lack**. One needs the definite or indefinite article  depending on the context: **There is a lack of information in this case** Or **The lack of information is prejudicing the outcome**.*Lack* here is equivalent to *shortage*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'There is lack of information' or 'There is a lack of information'?

In this case, it should be 'There is a lack of information', because the English language usually (with some exceptions) requires articles before nouns.